# How can I set the color of a selected row in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

The default background color of a selected row in DataGrid is so dark that I can't read it. Is there anyway of overriding it?

Tried this

```
<dg:DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type dg:DataGridRow}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True" >
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Gainsboro" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</dg:DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

But still nothing...

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Got it. Add the following within the DataGrid.Resources section:

```
  <DataGrid.Resources>
     <Style TargetType="{x:Type dg:DataGridCell}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="dg:DataGridCell.IsSelected" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#CCDAFF" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

Comment: This is great, I just ran into this and I was getting frustrated :-)

Comment: What section do you put that in?

Comment: Since the `BorderBrush` remains blue, if it annoys someone, just add another `Setter` element, which sets the `BorderBrush` dependency property to the same colour (value) as the `Background` itself.

Answer (score 179):

The above solution left blue border around each cell in my case.

This is the solution that worked for me. It is very simple, just add this to your `DataGrid`. You can change it from a `SolidColorBrush` to any other brush such as linear gradient.

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" 
                   Color="#FF0000"/>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

Comment: Perfect - exactly what I needed.  Allowed me to continue to reference an existing style for the DG and change the background brush for a selected row.

Comment: wounderfull. Any idea on how to do the same to foreground color?

Comment: Arsen, just override the brush for SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey in the same way to set the text color.

Comment: If I do select the entire row through Databinding e.g. `<DataGrid>ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MySelector}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"` the row is only LightGrey. Is there also a SystemColors?

´

Comment: Finally found the one if it doesn't have Focus: `SystemColors.ControlBrushKey`.

Comment: @Rolfi Excellent find!  Now, I wish there was something that could be done for selected ones that lose focus due to clicking on a different window.  It's a shame I can't see what's selected and have to click on the window again to check.

Comment: @Rolfi a word of warning if you override ControlBrushKey- it seems to be what the ContextMenu uses for its background color by default in only the Windows Classic theme... that was a fun one to debug!

Comment: @B.K. Probably `SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey`.

Comment: @Gerard I was pretty much brand spankin' new to the programming scene when I posted that comment, which was two years ago.  I can't remember what I ended up using, but yeah, something of that sort.

Comment: This was an excellent solution except for one thing... when I clicked a cell to highlight a row, I got a black border around the selected cell. I was able to remove the border using this solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4547422/4669311).

Answer (score 88):

As an extention to @Seb Kade's answer, you can fully control the colours of the selected and unselected rows using the following `Style`:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Transparent" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Black" />
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}" Color="Black" />
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

You can of course enter whichever colours you prefer. This `Style` will also work for other collection items such as `ListBoxItem`s (if you replace `TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}"` with `TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}"` for instance).

Comment: Your solution is best one.

Comment: Nice, Sheridan. I also want my row's foreground color on selected row. but it takes default HighlightTextBrushKey(i.e. black). what to do?

Comment: @deathrace.dj, If I understand you correctly, then you just need to change the `Color` property of the third `SolidColorbrush` in my example to whichever colour you like. Using this declaration is actually setting the colour of the `SolidColorbrush` that the `SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey` uses. Be careful though that you have not set the `Foreground` colour in another `Style` elsewhere as this can override the settings in the `Resources` above.

Comment: You may also want to set a transparent brush for `SystemColors.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrushKey`, or the row will highlight when the grid loses focus

Comment: Is there a SystemColor that I can override to change the foreground color of disabled cells globally? Thanks.

Comment: Great solution and it let me understand why I had SELECTED row color different from CLICKED row color (I use SelectionUnit="FullRow").

Answer (score 21):

I had this problem and I nearly tore my hair out, and I wasn't able to find the appropriate answer on the net. I was trying to control the background color of the selected row in a WPF DataGrid. It just wouldn't do it. In my case, the reason was that I also had a CellStyle in my datagrid, and the CellStyle overrode the RowStyle I was setting. Interestingly so, because the CellStyle wasn't even setting the background color, which was instead bing set by the RowBackground and AlternateRowBackground properties. Nevertheless, trying to set the background colour of the selected row did not work at all when I did this:

```
        <DataGrid ... >
        <DataGrid.RowBackground>
            ...
        </DataGrid.RowBackground>
        <DataGrid.AlternatingRowBackground>
            ...
        </DataGrid.AlternatingRowBackground>
        <DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Pink"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <DataGrid.CellStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding MyProperty}" />
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

and it did work when I moved the desired style for the selected row out of the row style and into the cell style, like so:

```
    <DataGrid ... >
        <DataGrid.RowBackground>
            ...
        </DataGrid.RowBackground>
        <DataGrid.AlternatingRowBackground>
            ...
        </DataGrid.AlternatingRowBackground>
        <DataGrid.CellStyle>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{Binding MyProperty}" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Pink"/>
                        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

Just posting this in case someone has the same problem.

Comment: This happens every time , the cell sets a foreground and every body targets the row.

Comment: I ran into this too, and I'm not even setting a CellStyle.  When I tried to set this on the row style, it only affected the non-cell elements.

Answer (score 13):

The default IsSelected trigger changes 3 properties, Background, Foreground & BorderBrush. If you want to change the border as well as the background, just include this in your style trigger.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type dg:DataGridCell}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="dg:DataGridCell.IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#CCDAFF" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: @Mark H, rather than making major changes to this answer this late in the game, you should add your own answer.

Answer (score 13):

Some of the reason which I experienced the row selected event not working

1. Style is set up for DataGridCell
2. Using Templated columns
3. Trigger is set up at the DataGridRow

This is what helped me. Setting the Style for DataGridCell

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
  <Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
      <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
      <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
    </Trigger>
  </Style.Triggers> 
</Style>
```

And since I was using a template column with a label inside, I bound the Foreground property to the container Foreground using RelativeSource binding:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
  <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Label Content="{Binding CategoryName,
                 Mode=TwoWay,
                 UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus}"
             Foreground="{Binding Foreground,
                 RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,
                     AncestorLevel=1, 
                     AncestorType={x:Type DataGridCell}}}"
             Width="150"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 4):

I've tried ControlBrushKey but it didn't work for unselected rows. The background for the unselected row was still white. But I've managed to find out that I have to override the rowstyle.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="pbSelectionDataGrid" Height="201" Margin="10,0"
          FontSize="20" SelectionMode="Single" FontWeight="Bold">
    <DataGrid.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}" Color="#FFFDD47C"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="#FFA6E09C"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}" Color="Red"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}" Color="Violet"/>
    </DataGrid.Resources>
    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="LightBlue" />
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 2):

I spent the better part of a day fiddling with this problem. Turned out the RowBackground Property on the DataGrid - which I had set - was overriding all attempts to change it in . As soon as I deleted it, everything worked.
(Same goes for Foreground set in DataGridTextColumn, by the way).