# How to suppress DataGrid cell selection border?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I've tried setting border style as suggested here [Disable DataGrid current cell border in FullRow selection mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547370/disable-datagrid-current-cell-border-in-fullrow-selection-mode), but it doesn't do the thing fully. Is disables cell border selection when you select using a mouse, but there is still a dashed cell border when making selection using keyboard. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

the dashed box you see is the cell's `FocusedVisualStyle`

you need to override it so that it is blank.

2 options here (one of them has to be the right one but as I didn't have time to try, I don't know which)

- the visualStyle is set on the cell directly

this means you have to set it through the `CellStyle` property:

```
<DataGrid.CellStyle>
   <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
      <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
   </Style>
</DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

or if you want to comply with MS's templating guidelines:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>

    <!--CellFocusVisual-->
    <Style x:Key="CellFocusVisual">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Border>
                        <Rectangle StrokeThickness="0" Stroke="#00000000" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                    </Border>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</DataGrid.Resources>

<DataGrid.CellStyle>
   <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
      <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource CellFocusVisual}"/>
   </Style>
</DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

(this way, you can see how it is done)

- other option: it is done via the `ElementStyle` or the `EditingElementStyle`

this is more of a hasle there, because the `ElementStyle` and `EditingElementStyle` are defined on the Column, wich means you have to edit each column's `ElementStyle` and `EditingElementStyle`.

but basically, this is the same thing: you set up the FocusVisualStyle to null or the style defined above through the `ElementStyle` and/or `EditingElementStyle` on each Column

Answer (score 9):

You can set Focusable to False.

```
<DataGrid ...
      SelectionUnit="FullRow">
   <DataGrid.CellStyle>
      <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
         <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
         <Setter Property="Focusable" Value="False"/>
      </Style>
   </DataGrid.CellStyle>
   <!-- ... -->
</DataGrid>
```

Note that if you make DataGridCell.Focusable false then navigation in the datagrid with up/down arrow keys won't work.

Comment: FYI - If you make DataGridCell.Focusable false then navigation in the datagrid w/ up/down arrow keys won't work.