# Removing box / border around selected cell contents in WPF DataGrid

Tags: wpf, xaml, datagrid

Trying to restyle a WPF datagrid. Almost where I need to be, except for one peculiarity: when selecting a row, the contents of all the cells are surrounded by a white border.

[image]

I'm at a loss as to how to get rid of this. At the moment, my styling looks like this:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent" />
    <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#3CACDC" />
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="#90C8E0" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Plus DataGridCell has an almost identical style set.

It's not clear whether the question [How to suppress DataGrid cell selection border?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5468678/how-to-suppress-datagrid-cell-selection-border) is asking the same question, but the accepted solution of setting `FocusVisualStyle` to `Null` doesn't remove the border. It does, however, change the style:

[image]

How can I get ride of that border?

Comment: is there any style except that you posted above? Is it all xaml related to DataGrid? I cannot reproduce a such behavior. Selected row is highlighted by blue color and selected cell has black border.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I have the same problem. As you mention in your comment, the Accepted Answer doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can try styling DataGridCell style

```
   <DataGrid.CellStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>          
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
    </Style>
  </DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

Comment: Sorry, typo in the question. I've already tried that on both the Cell and the Row.

Comment: please try using SelectionUnit="FullRow" in the datagrid