# Select one row in DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, select, row

I set `SelectionUnit="FullRow"` to a `WPF` `DataGrid` but when I select it seems to still focus over the cell that the mouse click was fired.

How to not focus on any cell and select only a row?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable DataGrid current cell border in FullRow selection mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4547370/disable-datagrid-current-cell-border-in-fullrow-selection-mode)

Comment: Thanks! it did the trick.

Comment: I suppose that your problem is only visual. Isn't it?
You can modify ControlTemplate of Cell and cancel and remove Trigger that resposible for this black border.