# WPF DataGrid RowStyle for selected row not changing the background and foreground color

Tags: wpf, datagrid, background-color

I am using Visual Studio 2012 on windows 7. I need to know why the following style for Grid's selected row does not work for background and foreground colors but works perfectly fine for other properties like BorderBrush and BorderThickness etc? Though I can see them changing while mouse over grid rows.

```
<Style x:Key="gridRowStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="PeachPuff"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="BlueViolet"/>
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="PeachPuff"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="BlueViolet"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="BlueViolet" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="2" />

        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Here is how I am using on grid.

```
<DataGrid RowStyle="{StaticResource gridRowStyle}">
```

I am stressing on to know "why" rather than solution to the problem as I already have solution to problem if I use grid cell style instead of rowstyle like following:

```
<Style x:Key="gridCellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="PeachPuff"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="BlueViolet"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Comment: Could it be because the GridCell content is overlaying the GridRow? Have you tried looked at the control in Snoop?

Comment: I ran a quick test with what you posted and it works fine.  Can you give more detail on you DataGrid and any Row definitions?

Comment: I am new to WPF and I never used snoop before. I will give it a try to see what is happening. Thanks....

Comment: @BrentStewart, well here is the entire defination of DataGrid:<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"                  
                  ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource RecordList}}"
                  RowStyle="{StaticResource gridRowStyle}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="First Name" Binding="{Binding FirstName}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Last Name" Binding="{Binding LastName}" Width="*"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>

Comment: where RecordList is custom collection of objects of simple class Record which has two public properties FirstName and LastName defined in current window resources:
public class Record
    {
        public string FirstName
        {
            set;
            get;
        }
        public string LastName
        {
            set;
            get;
        }
    }
public class MyCollection : ObservableCollection<Record>
    {
    }

Comment: I defined the RecordList collection as follow:
<Window.Resources>
        <local:MyCollection x:Key="RecordList">
            <local:Record FirstName="Naeem" LastName="Ashraf"/>
            <local:Record FirstName="Faheem" LastName="Ashraf"/>
            <local:Record FirstName="Asghar" LastName="Qayyum"/>            
        </local:MyCollection>            
 </Window.Resources>

Comment: Hmm, well I still can not recreate your issue.  Copying and pasting your code to a new WPF project works as expected.  I second the suggestion of using Snoop to see what is actually going on.  Let us know what you find out.

Comment: @BrentStewart According to my findings from Snoop, in selected row the background of row is of what I defined in my style. But if I check the row's cell it is having different background value "#FF3399FF" coming from "Default style trigger"(Value Source tab in snoop). Also in case of mouse over cell background value is transparent with value source in snoop becoming "Default Style".

Comment: So do you have a default DataGridCell style defined somewhere in your app? In a resource dictionary, or your generic.xaml?

Comment: There is nothing in my application for DataGridCell style. I don't know from where it is being set. As I stated in start of posting, I am using visual studio 2012 on windows 7.

Comment: What selection mode do u have set?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223280/how-can-i-set-the-color-of-a-selected-row-in-datagrid

Answer (score 0):

In the Default style of the DataGridCell having the following default style trigger.

```
<Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightTextBrushKey}}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}}"/>
</Trigger>
```

So if you written trigger for DataGridRow, then it will only apply to the element that was placed before the DataGridCell in visual tree.

So to change the Background & Foreground while selection, you must write the trigger in DataGridCell style or remove the default trigger from the style.

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove this attributs at row level in the datagrid, they have priority over the trigged properties.

nezac