# DataGridRow in DataGrid MVVM

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, binding, datagrid

How can I change row color in my DataGrid using MVVM?

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedIndex, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAction, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ItemsSource="{Binding students1}">
```

and I have property as

```
 public Model.Student SelectedAction { get; set; }
 public int SelectedIndex { get; set; }
```

How change DataGrid Row Color for selected item?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I set the color of a selected row in DataGrid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223280/how-can-i-set-the-color-of-a-selected-row-in-datagrid)