# wpf datagrid cell style based on row item value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid

This should be relatively easy to do, but for some reason, I am not getting it to work. I have a class `ViewWrapper` that has a property `ViewGroup` and `ViewGroupEditable`. I have a column in my datagrid that is bound to `ViewGroup` property, and now I want to disable editing on that cell if the property `ViewGroupEditable` is false. So I created a `DataGridCell` style with simple data trigger, but its not doing anything. What did i miss?

XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="GrimshawRibbon.Revit.Views.ViewManager.ViewManagerView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:GrimshawRibbon.Revit.Views.ViewManager"
             xmlns:ex="clr-namespace:GrimshawRibbon.Revit.Wpf.Extensions"
             xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
             xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Platform"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="500">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Fonts.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/Blue.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MahApps.Metro;component/Styles/Accents/BaseLight.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/GrimshawRibbon;component/Revit/Wpf/Style/GrimshawTheme.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="dgCellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type DataGridCell}}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ViewGroupEditable}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightGray"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <ex:DataGridEx x:Name="dgViews" 
                               Style="{StaticResource AzureDataGrid}" 
                               Margin="10" 
                               AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                               ItemsSource="{Binding Views, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                               CanUserAddRows="False" 
                               IsReadOnly="False" 
                               SelectionMode="Extended" 
                               SelectionUnit="FullRow" 
                               SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRow, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                               SelectedItemsList="{Binding SelectedViews, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="CellEditEnding">
                    <cmd:EventToCommand PassEventArgsToCommand="True" Command="{Binding CellEditEndingCommand}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="*"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="ViewType" Binding="{Binding ViewType}" Width="100" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="ViewGroup" Binding="{Binding ViewGroup, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="130" CellStyle="{StaticResource dgCellStyle}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="ViewSubGroup" Binding="{Binding ViewSubGroup, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Width="130" IsReadOnly="False"/>
                <DataGridCheckBoxColumn ElementStyle="{DynamicResource MetroDataGridCheckBox}" 
                                        EditingElementStyle="{DynamicResource MetroDataGridCheckBox}" 
                                        Header="OnSheet" 
                                        Binding="{Binding OnSheet, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                                        IsReadOnly="True" 
                                        Width="80">
                </DataGridCheckBoxColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="ViewTemplate" Width="180">
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ViewTemplate.Name}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding DataContext.ViewTemplates, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"
                                      SelectedItem="{Binding ViewTemplate}"
                                      DisplayMemberPath="Name">
                                <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                                        <cmd:EventToCommand PassEventArgsToCommand="True"
                                                            Command="{Binding DataContext.SelectChangeCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}"/>
                                    </i:EventTrigger>
                                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            </ComboBox>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </ex:DataGridEx>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Each row in the data grid is bound to an object like this:

```
public class ViewWrapper : ElementWrapper
    {
        public string ViewType { get; set; }
        public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
        public bool OnSheet { get; set; }
        public string ViewGroup { get; set; }
        public string ViewSubGroup { get; set; }
        public ViewWrapper ViewTemplate { get; set; }
        public bool ViewGroupEditable { get; set; }
        public bool ViewSubGroupEditable { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem I can see is that `ViewWrapper` does not implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. You should use something like this for all your properties:

```
public class ViewWrapper : ElementWrapper, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    string _viewSubGroup;
    public string ViewSubGroup { get { return _viewSubGroup; } set { _viewSubGroup = value; RaisePropertyChanged("ViewSubGroup"); } } 

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    void RaisePropertyChanged(string propname)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propname));
    }
}
```

See [this post](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) among many others.

Comment: The `ElementWrapper` class that it inherits from does implement that. It's an `ObservableObject` class.

Comment: Even then, you need ``RaisePropertyChanged("ViewSubGroup");`` (or something similar) in the setter part of the properties to raise the event.

Comment: Indeed, I missed that. Great suggestion. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

`DataGridTextColumn` does not have `IsEnabled` property, so it cannot be set. You may try `IsReadOnly` instead (mind that you will be disabling the whole column).

You may have  more luck with this approach:

```
 <DataGridTextColumn Width="80" Header="My column header" Binding="{Binding Path=MyProperty, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
       <Style TargetType="TextBox">
           <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="{Binding IsEditingEnabled}"/>
       </Style>
    </DataGridTextColumn.EditingElementStyle>
  </DataGridTextColumn>
```

You can define two styles for data displayed in your column: the normal style (`ElementStyle`) and the way it will appear while in edit mode (`EditingElementStyle`). Although you may want to do some more styling in this case to have consistent appearance for both `TextBlock` and `TextBox`.

Or this way (untested):

```
 <Style x:Key="dgCellStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}"">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ViewGroupEditable}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="LightGray"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
  </Style>

  <DataGridTextColumn Header="ViewGroup" 
       Binding="{Binding ViewGroup, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
       Width="130" 
       EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource dgCellStyle}"/>
```

Comment: so it looks like my data setters are working. what is not behaving is my background color. it changes to dark blue when row is selected. is that related to what you are saying about textbox?

Comment: @konrad that is the default selection color, this should help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/1227929/891715