# Data grid selected row color change (still don't get it)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I've read this post  [How can I set the color of a selected row in DataGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223280/how-can-i-set-the-color-of-a-selected-row-in-datagrid) and they have a lot of good answers but none of this answers worked for me ot maybe i did not implement the code on the correct place.

i haven't changed anything like making a cell style of my own but i'n using the next packages: MahApps.Metro,MvvM.light.libs,EF,Extended wpf toolkit (XCEED)
this last one i added to try something to solve the problem but still didn't work.

Could this packages cause me problems ?? 
i have tried all of the solutions of the post i mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Could this packages cause me problems ??

Yes, MahApps.Metro overrides the default `DataGrid` styles and uses different resource keys than the system style.

You simply need to adapt the answer from the linked question to accommodate the MahApps resource keys:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MetroDataGrid.HighlightBrush"
                   Color="Crimson" />  <!-- Set your own color here -->
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

There are some related background brushes you might want to override too:

- `MetroDataGrid.InactiveSelectionHighlightBrush`
- `MetroDataGrid.MouseOverHighlightBrush`
- `MetroDataGrid.DisabledHighlightBrush`

And some foreground brushes:

- `MetroDataGrid.HighlightTextBrush`
- `MetroDataGrid.InactiveSelectionHighlightTextBrush`

You can inspect the [MahApps styles on GitHub](http://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/develop/src/MahApps.Metro/MahApps.Metro/Styles/Controls.DataGrid.xaml) to see what brush resources they use, and when.

Comment: the same would go for a **ComboBox**?

Comment: It looks that way.  [Check the styles](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/develop/src/MahApps.Metro/MahApps.Metro/Styles/Controls.ComboBox.xaml) for yourself.