# IsHitTestVisible=false is disabling the ScrollBar of the DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to disallow selection of the `DataGrid`, so I am setting the property `IsHitTestVisible` to false, but then it also disables the `ScrollBar`.

How can I enable scrollbar by still disabling the selection on the `DataGrid`?

One thing I can do is:
I can change the selection color on the `DataGrid`. Problem is when I say Trigger `Property="DataGridRow.IsSelected"` it won't work. On the other hand if I say `TriggerProperty="DataGridCell.IsSelected"` like it says here [Row Selection in DataGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223280/how-can-i-set-the-color-of-a-selected-row-in-datagrid/9633703), it only selects the first column and not the entire row. Also if I say that the Value is Transparent for the Background it dosen't show the text in the cell. Please help.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DGRunInfoItems" IsHitTesVisible="False" IsReadOnly="True" ColumnWidth="*" FontSize="{StaticResource BRControlNormalFontSize}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HeadersVisibility="None" CanUserAddRows="False" ItemsSource="{Binding RunViewModel.RunInfoDataTable}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Header}">
      <DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
          <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="DataGridCell.IsSelected" Value="True">
              <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            </Trigger>
          </Style.Triggers>
          <Style.Setters>
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
          </Style.Setters>
        </Style>
      </DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
    </DataGridTextColumn>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Value}"/>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
  <DataGrid.RowStyle>
    <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
      <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="28"/>
    </Style>
  </DataGrid.RowStyle>
</DataGrid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked finally.. I got it achieved with the help of a style by removing the IsHitTestVisible. Incase if it helps someone here is the solution. I applied a style to the whole DataGrid. Please see the DataGrid.CellStyle. (I got this help from another StackOverflow post but can't find the link to it.)

```
<DataGrid x:Name="DGRunInfoItems"  IsReadOnly="True" ColumnWidth="*" FontSize="{StaticResource BRControlNormalFontSize}" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" HeadersVisibility="None" CanUserAddRows="False" ItemsSource="{Binding RunViewModel.RunInfoDataTable}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="DataGridCell.IsSelected" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <SolidColorBrush Color="Transparent"/>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                    <Setter Property="Foreground"
                            Value="{DynamicResource
                                   {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="Background">
                                        <Setter.Value>
                                            <SolidColorBrush Color="Transparent"/>
                                        </Setter.Value>
                                    </Setter>
                                </Trigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGrid.CellStyle>
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Header}" FontWeight="Bold">
                        </DataGridTextColumn>
                        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Value}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGrid.RowStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="DataGridRow">
                            <Setter Property="MinHeight" Value="28"/>
                        </Style>
                    </DataGrid.RowStyle>
                </DataGrid>
```